# onAttach(Context context) not being called

Tags: android, debugging, dialogfragment

I am trying to create an `DialogFragment` for an android application using API 23. I found that the `onAttach` method has been updated for this API, needing now a `Context` as an argument. The problem is, I just cannot get my `DialogFragment` to get attached to my `Activity`. I'm getting the following exceptions:

```
02-10 21:09:31.852 22647-22647/com.dactylotech.dactylo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.dactylotech.dactylo, PID: 22647
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment ConnectionTypeAlertDialogFragment{c9d04dd} not attached to Activity
     at android.app.Fragment.getResources(Fragment.java:805)
     at android.app.Fragment.getString(Fragment.java:827)
     at com.dactylotech.dactylo.ConnectionTypeAlertDialogFragment.<init>(ConnectionTypeAlertDialogFragment.java:17)
     at com.dactylotech.dactylo.ListBTDevicesActivity$PairedBTDevicesClickable.onItemClick(ListBTDevicesActivity.java:129)
     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:310)
     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1145)
     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3049)
     at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3886)
     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

After doing a thorough research and having found no real answer, and instead discovering many people having the exact same problem and claiming it was bugged, I decided to look into the code for `onAttach`, which is the following:

```
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    mCalled = true;
    final Activity hostActivity = mHost == null ? null : mHost.getActivity();
    if (hostActivity != null) {
        mCalled = false;
        onAttach(hostActivity);
    }
}
```

If I'm not mistaken, `hostActivity` can either be assigned `null` or `mHost.getActivity()`. However, as this is the first call to `mHost` (following android's `Fragment` lifecycle), `mHost` is null from the beginning. This means that the expression evaluates to `TRUE` and so, it gets assigned `null` again!! Again, if I'm not mistaken, this is why `onAttach(hostActivity)` is never called, and therefore the DialogFragment is never attached to the `Activity`.

My question is, am I correct? Is this why this is happening? I want to get another point of view at this. Is there any way to get around this?

EDIT:
The code displayed here for `onAttach` is the code from the `Fragment` java class. (`android.app.Fragment`)

EDIT #2:
Whelp, it seems there is no error at all. Solution to my problem has been posted.

Comment: `@Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);}` this should be the onAttach function. Your one is not very familiar to me.

Comment: This is the code for the `onAttach` method found in the `android.app.Fragment` class. This is not the `onAttach` code I'm using for MY `DialogFragment` class.

Answer (score 3):

In your fragment's constructor you're calling to `Fragment.getString()`. This method requires a context to fetch the resources to fetch the string and thus tries to get the activity.

`Fragment ConnectionTypeAlertDialogFragment{c9d04dd} not attached to Activity` tells you that the activity is not set. This is because the constructor is called before any other life-cycle event like `onAttach()`.

You should refrain from doing any initialization of the fragment in the constructor and only use the life-cycle events. Like this you can ensure the state you need. Instead you could move the logic around `getString()` to `onAttach()` for example.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked. I was trying to declare a CharSequence as a global variable in my DialogFragment class, but using getString to get the resources.